# Scrolling model dialog in gtk3? how to do it

Tags: python, pygtk, glade, gtk3

does any one know how to create a modal dialog that scrolls in from the top of the parent window (like the about window in glade 3.10). I'm using Glade 3.10 with python. I tried creating a dialog and a normal window, setting it's properties to modal and popup,... but that doesn't seem to do the trick, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [set the dialog transient for](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-transient-for) the parent window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried setting the transient property of my dialog to my main window. Didn't work for me, however googling suggests that your solution is the right one, so i guess I'm doing something wrong.

I created a gladefile, in which my main window resides. I also created a dialog inside this gladefile. I set the properties modal to yes for the dialog, window type to popup and "window transient for" to my main window. In a button click handler for my main window I call the dialog with show(). Dialog appears as a modal popup, but not with the scrolling effect; (I'm using gnome 3).

Comment: You may have to call the dialog with `run()`, I'm not sure.

Comment: Same result, but then again, it _should_ work they way you told me. Thanks for the answer. Guess it's misconfiguration on my side...

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with gtk3?